# video.js Subtitles won't load

Tags: javascript, video.js, subtitle

I just downloaded the opensource video player Video.js and opend up the demo in Chrome and IE and with both the subtitles won't play.

Source files: http://www.videojs.com/

I haven't changed anything and this is the error i get while reading the console in Chrome:

> Text track from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading: Not at
>   same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have
>   a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: Hello, do you know what "Same origin policy" is ?

Comment: I understand it a littlebit, it has to do something with sercurity. but this shoudn't be importend if I just downloaded the demo files right?

Comment: It seems to be important, could you edit your question to add all the HTML code, so that we could help better?

Comment: I just downloaded the video player from http://www.videojs.com/ and opend up the demo file without editing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens in Chrome, but not in Firefox, this is due to Same origin policy:

you must have double-clicked on the demo file, leading to opening the demo.html file in your default browser (which seems to be Chrome) with the `file://` protocol. Since the browser is given the order to get the subtitles with the `http://` protocol, the browser refuses to get them.

So you can either:

- put all the files in a webserver (really easy with node and browser-sync on live-server, but you can just as easily use apache or nginx) and you are done
- download the subtitles, put the files in the same directory as the rest, and change the HTML to point to its relative path from `demo.html`

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tested it on mozilla and it worked indeed. I will try it on the server later!